# Querying into a memory table

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, datatable, in-memory-tables

SQL Server lets you create in-memory tables. But how do you do insert into operation on that?

So for example, I used this code to create my type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.typeTableDelimetedFileSpec  
       AS TABLE  
          (  
               TemplateId INT NOT NULL,  
               FieldName VARCHAR(50) NOT NUL,
               FieldPosition SMALLINT NOT NULL INDEX fpos
          )  
          WITH (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON);
```

Then, I tried to do this:

```
DECLARE @T [dbo].[typeTableDelimetedFileSpec]

SELECT * 
INTO @T 
FROM [dbo].[_DelimetedFileSpec] 
WHERE TemplateId = 1
```

I know the structures match (`_DelimetedFileSpec` does not have index fpos, but other than that there are no differences).

I get:
Incorrect syntax near '@T'.

Also, just to check out that there are no other errors, I confirmed that the following works fine:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #x 
FROM [dbo].[_DelimetedFileSpec] 
WHERE TemplateId = 1
```

Is it possible to somehow insert directly into the memory-table, like this?

Comment: You tried to do "this" and what happened? Don't just gloss over the fact that an error occurred. "select ... into ..." CREATES a table. You declared a table variable, so you insert into it. You already know exactly how to do this since that technique was used as an answer in your previous question. And no - you can't use the "select ... into ..." form to both create and populate your table variable. TSQL is strictly type (mostly) and your attempt to do dynamic schemas on the cheap are not going to work.

Comment: Incorrect syntax near '@T'    I will update the question to match...

Comment: ok, i will insert into it.  i thought maybe there is some efficient way to do this that I don't know of....

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it efficiently!

```
Declare @DeliSpecs [dbo].[typeTableDelimetedFileSpec]
Insert into @DeliSpecs (TemplateId, FieldName, FieldPosition) Select TemplateId, FieldName, FieldPosition from _DelimetedFileSpec where TemplateId = @Id
```